How do I count fields with the same value ("Completed"), each field is on a different table?
I have a form that includes fields from multiple tables. The values are in drop down combo boxes ith "Completed" as one of the options.
These are the field names from each table (ConceptStatus, ProductStatus, ComplianceStatus etc.)
I have a field called CompletedSubTasks where I want to count all the (status) fields where they have a "Completed" value.
This is just one of the different attempt i made, I would also like the CompletedSubTasks field to update when the status (Concept,Product,Compliance) are updated/changed. I currently have it on click because I can't work out how to make it update when one of the status fields is changed.
Private Sub CompletedSubTasks_Click()

    If ([ConceptStatus] = "Completed" And [ProductStatus] = "Completed" And [ComplianceStatus] = "Completed") Then
        CompletedSubTasks = [ConceptStatus] + [ProductStatus] + [ComplianceStatus]       
    End If

End Sub


You could set the ControlSource of CompletedSubTasks to this expression:
=Abs([ConceptStatus]="Completed")+Abs([ProductStatus]="Completed")+Abs([ComplianceStatus]="Completed")


That was so much simpler than expected, thanks! Really appreciate it!

Great! Then please mark as answered.
